Check if an .rpm file exists in a repo/location based on contents of a file
I have an internal SLES repo that contains numerous packages/dependencies - they are stored under various sub directories like src, noarch, x86_64, etc.
I also have a list of packages/dependencies that are needed - I am trying to check if the packages/dependencies I have in my file are stored/can be found in my internal SLES repo. If it does exist, then skip that line in the file, if it doesn't exist then save this line to a new file so that I can any and all missing packages/dependencies.
I have tried a few things now, such as:
SLES_ALIAS=<repo-alias>
MY_REPO=<some/url/internal-sles-repo>

repo_pkg_list="../repo/required_pkgs.list"
missing_pkg_list="../repo/missing_cbo_pkg.list"

while IFS= read -r rpm; do
    found=false

    for subdir in noarch src x86_64; do
        if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$MY_REPO/$subdir/$rpm"; then
            found=true
            break
        fi
    done

    if ! $found; then
        echo "RPM not found: $rpm"
    fi
done < "$repo_pkg_list"

So I'm trying to go through each subdir in MY_REPO and check for the .rpm listed in my file. My file and the the rpms in MY_REPO appear as so:
expat-2.4.4-150400.3.17.1.x86_64.rpm
filesystem-15.0-11.8.1.x86_64.rpm
fillup-1.42-2.18.x86_64.rpm
findutils-4.8.0-1.20.x86_64.rpm
fontconfig-2.13.1-150400.1.4.x86_64.rpm
fonts-config-20200609+git0.42e2b1b-150000.4.10.1.noarch.rpm
gawk-4.2.1-150000.3.3.1.x86_64.rpm

I have also tried:
while IFS= read -r line; do
    package_found=false

    for subdir in x86_64 src noarch; do
        if zypper --non-interactive-download "$MY_REPO$line"; then
            echo "Downloaded: $line"
        else
            echo "$line" >> "$missing_pkg_list"
            echo "Failed to download: $line, adding to $missing_pkg_list"
        fi
    done
done < "$repo_pkg_list"


I don't use SLES but the manpage suggests something like zypper search -r your-repo-uri -s NAME.ARCH might give useful output
